# Break up long for statement

Tags: python, for-loop, pep8, long-lines

I can't find an answer within the PEP 8 style guide.
Is there a possibility to break up a long `for` statement by using round brackets instead of a backslash?

The following will result in a syntax error:

```
for (one, two, three, four, five in
     one_to_five):
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the long part is the unpacking, I would just avoid it:

```
for parts in iterable:
    one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight = parts
```

Or if it is really long:

```
for parts in iterable:
    (one, two, three, four,
     five, six, seven, eight) = parts
```

If the `iterable` is a long expression you should put it in a line by itself *before* the loop:

```
iterable = the_really_long_expression(
               eventually_splitted,
               on_multiple_lines)
for one, two, three in iterable:
```

If *both* are long then you can just combine these conventions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use brackets after the `in` keyword:

```
for (one, two, three, four, five) in (
                    one_to_five):
    pass
```

In your question, as posted, you accidentally dropped the opening bracket, which causes the syntax error you are getting.