# PEP-8 break up for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pep8, flake8

I am trying to figure out a way to break a long for loop to make it PEP-8 valid.
(I'm using flake8 vscode extension).

This is the code:

```
for result_row in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b2c-inner-data-wrapper"}):
    ..............
```

The error I get is:

```
line too long (88 > 79 characters)
```

I've tried:

```
for result_row in soup.find_all('div',
{"class": "b2c-inner-data-wrapper"}):
```

But I get:

```
continuation line under-indented for visual indent
```

What is the right way of doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can not reproduce. That line is only 76 characters.

Comment: if you install black and run it on your file, it will reformat to match the pep-8 linting rules.  or if not,  i would indent the  contents of findall's parentheses on a newline

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328894/break-up-long-for-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break up long for statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328894/break-up-long-for-statement)

Answer (score 1):

```py
result_rows = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b2c-inner-data-wrapper"})
for result_row in result_rows:
    ..............
```

Comment: What if I am short on memory and the iterator takes a lot of it? If the for-loop is inside a method or function, I'd be fine. But if I am writing a long script or a notebook, I would have to `del results_rows` after the loop to garbage collect the iterator. Am I right? So your answer won't work in all cases.

Comment: Huh?   The iterator is going to take what it takes... the question is about line-length.  But I have another one for you I'll add

Answer (score 1):

```
for result_row in soup.find_all(
        'div',
        {"class": "b2c-inner-data-wrapper"}
):
```